# Fixing button size in button

Tags: css

I have a problem with the size of the button. I am trying to avoid specifying the size (the text is no problem), realizing that the size of the button will be big. I only want to go back when I'm selecting the image not the whole button

Here is the image:

[image: http://imgur.com/Hsf5Eci]

Code:

```
background: url(https://static.mijnwebwinkel.nl/winkel/belatex/images/003078.jpg) no-repeat;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 10px;
background-size: 17px;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
white-space: nowrap;
transform: scaleX(-1);
right: 20px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
background-color: transparent;
cursor: default;
```

Comment: In the picture, what is "the button"?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the image and not the whole button might not be possible and I can't see as it would be necessary as if one clicks anywhere on the button isn't that what you want anyway, as some might not click perfectly on the arrow?  For the button size, do you want a smaller or larger button?  If larger, it seems just doubling the size & padding pixels would do that easily, if smaller just halving.